# How to catch integrity constraint deletion error?

Tags: spring, hibernate

There are two database tables role and role_menu. There is foreign key in role_menu referencing role's primary key.

Now I am deleting a row of the master table role which row has a foreign key associated in role_menu. I tried to enclose the delete code inside try catch but the execution does not enter in the catch block :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(String role_code) {
    try {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete((Role) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Role.class, role_code));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error : there is fk !");
    }

}
```

In console I got these texts :

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 2292, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-02292: integrity constraint (PTA.FK_ROLE_MEN_R_ROLE_ME_ROLE) violated - child record found
```

So how to deal with integrity constraint deletion error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the fact that the exception is thrown only when the session is flush to the database just before the transaction is committed. Since you are using the `@Transactional` annotation, it is happening at the end of the method right after the catch block. Flushing the session at the end of the try block should do the trick :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(String role_code) {
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.delete((Role) session.get(Role.class, role_code));
        session.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error : there is fk !");
    }
}
```

Note that it may be better to avoid using the flush there and catch the exception at another level, but it depends on the use case.

Comment: you just can't catch it at another level as transaction will be already marked as rollback. Anyway, all of this is a very bad idea and breaks several principles cf. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html "If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs."

Comment: Catching the exception at another level implies that the transaction is also created at an other level and then propagate to this function...